# JSON parse database to String

Tags: java, json

I created an application that uses JSON for the database, and it seems to write fine, and the file reader reads the database fine, but I cant seem to get the database values from the database value.

here is my parsing code:

```
  String userEnteredString = UserEntered.getText(); 
    String userHomeLocal = Tutschedule.userHome; 
    Reader dataFile = null; 
    try {
        dataFile = new FileReader(userHomeLocal+"/Users/"+userEnteredString+".data");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String dbData = dataFile.toString();
    try {
        JSONObject dbObject = new JSONObject(dbData);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(dbData); 
    JSONObject dataInfo = new JSONObject(dbData);
    String password = dataInfo.getString("password");
    System.out.println(password); 

    BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(dataFile); 
    String test = null; 
    try { 
        test = buffered.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The problem is when I print password it doesnt print anything, leading me to think that the password field is not processed.

here is an example of the database:

```
{"username":"user","password":"test"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals The question is clear if you take the time to read the post.

Comment: it would be useful if you posted the output of the above code.  ie, does "example of the database" get printed when `System.out.println(dbData);`  is executed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe FileReader.toString() is doing what you think it's doing. FileReader inherits toString from object, which means that it is just going to print out the reference, not the contents of the file, and yet you are trying to parse that as JSON. In that case you should have a severe log message though.

In order to read the contents of the file, you should use the `read` method on the reader or make it easy on yourself and use commons-io FileUtils#readFileToString or something similar.